# Use global variable

Tags: html, css, less

Studying conducting experimentation.

How I get global variable?

```
@reds:#bb22cc;
div{

@reds:#aaaa88;
p{

color:@reds;
background://how to get global @reds:#bb22cc;
}
}
```

Comment: Seems obvious, but why not just use a different variable name?

Comment: Question is too broad. What exactly is the question? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: @Paulie_D He wants to use the local variable *and* the global one although they share the same name.

Comment: Use like, `@reds2` or something for your global variable.

Comment: If this is not possible it does not mean that I did not read the documentation  .Wesley Much YES!

Comment: Please explain why using a different variable name is not acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, just use a different variable name.

```
@reds: #bb22cc;

div {
    @reds2: #aaaa88;
    p{
        color: @reds2;
        background: @reds;
    }
}
```

`@reds2` won't be leaked to the global scope.

Comment: maybee variable of variable?

Comment: Once you overwrite the variable, you can't access the original value. Can you please explain why you need to use the same variable name?

Comment: example2 doesnt work...

Comment: You're right, it doesn't, removed. Can you please explain why you need to use the same variable name? Does it make you uncomfortable that what you are asking cannot be done? If there is some context we are missing, please explain.

Comment: I use the same variable name because I study all aspects of less.I try to upgrade version of less.

Comment: OK well you need to use a different variable name to accomplish this. You had a problem upgrading? Please be more clear.